# Covert a 2D Matrix to a 3D array

Tags: r

I am currently running climate4R packages (downscaleR, TransformeR, VisualizeR, and LoadeR) for climate models downscaling. I encountered a problem regarding array. My observed data is a station based data in 2D (time, loc) and the predictors variables are in 3D array (time, lat, lon).
I loaded my observed station data (precip.txt, station.txt and variable.txt file) based on the loadeR as;

```r
obsdata <- "C:/R_workstation/downscaling/observations" 
stationInfo(obsdata)
di.obsdata <- dataInventory(obsdata)
y <- loadStationData(dataset = obsdata,
                     var = "precip",
                     lonLim = lonLim,
                     latLim = latLim,
                     years = years) %>% binaryGrid(condition = "GE",
                                                   threshold = 1.5,
                                                   partial = TRUE)
```

I decided to use the `mat2Dto3Darray` function in the transformeR package to convert the station data to 3d array. The function help reads:

> Description
>
> Converts a 2D matrix of the form [time, lonlat] to a 3D array of the form [time,lat,lon], in this order. Mainly for PCA analysis and grid reconstruction.
>
> Usage
>
> `mat2Dto3Darray(mat2D, x, y)`
>
> Arguments
>
> `mat2D`: A 2D matrix with time in rows and lonlat in columns, as returned by `array3Dto2Dmat`
>
> `x`: unique X coordinates of the points, in ascending order
>
> `y`: As argument x, for the Y coordinates.

Following the description, I loaded my x and y coordinate as follows;

```r
x <- c(7.93, 8.29, 8.38, 8.43, 8.74, 8.83, 9.07, 9.35, 9.57, 9.82, 10.211, 10.45, 10.53, 11.05)
y <- c(10.6, 10.74, 11.09, 11.47, 11.56, 11.657, 11.71, 11.79, 11.92, 11.97, 12.123, 12.31, 12.86, 12.87),
```

Then I used the loaded observed data (`y`) as my `mat2D` and I encountered this error:

> Error in 1:nrow(mat2D) : argument of length 0".

How can I convert my observed data (`y`) to 3D array using the `mat2Dto3Darray(mat2D, x, y)` function for further analysis?